# How to create a Python dictionary with sub items from an API?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I've got a response from an API similar to the below which contains a list of products, some of these products are sub products, almost like a bundle.  I wanted to produce an output similar to the below:

```
Main SKU 1
    1 Sub Product(s)
    Sub SKU - Something
    Id

Main SKU 2
    2 Sub Product(s)
    Sub SKU - Something
    Id
```

With the API data looking like this:

```
    {
    "DisplayName": "Main SKU 1",
    "Id": "1",
},
    {
    "DisplayName": "Main SKU 2",
    "Id": "2",
},
{
    "DisplayName": "Sub SKU - Something",
    "Id": "3",
    "ParentRef": {
    "value": "1"
    }
},
    {
    "DisplayName": "Sub SKU - Something Else",
    "Id": "4",
    "ParentRef": {
    "value": "2"
    }
},
    {
    "DisplayName": "Sub SKU - Something Else Again", 
    "Id": "5",
    "ParentRef": {
    "value": "2"
    }
}
```

and I want to create an output to the console like:

```
Main SKU 1
    1 Sub Product(s)
    Sub SKU - Something
    Id

Main SKU 2
    2 Sub Product(s)
    Sub SKU - Something
    Id
```

Currently I am iterating through each item to get a list of Main, then again with just the Subs but I'm struggling to put them together.  My nested loops are getting out of hand and I'm sure I shouldn't be iterating several times to get the output.

I just want pointing in right direction, I'm not expecting my code to be written for me.

Comment: Your question is not really clear. Try to rephrase and explain it better.

Comment: what is your *API data*, a string? a list of dicts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this to create a tree structure which will contain a `dict` in which the `key` will be the `Id of the parent` and the `value` will be the `list of its children`:

```
data = {}
for sku in _input
    if 'ParentRef' not in sku:
        data[sku['Id']] = []

for sku in bla:
    if 'ParentRef' in _input:
        data[sku['ParentRef']['value']].append(sku)
```

Example input:

```
_input = [
    {
        "DisplayName": "Main SKU 1",
        "Id": "1",
    },
    {
        "DisplayName": "Main SKU 2",
        "Id": "2",
    },
    {
        "DisplayName": "Sub SKU - Something",
        "Id": "3",
        "ParentRef": {
            "value": "1"
        }
    },
    {
        "DisplayName": "Sub SKU - Something Else",
        "Id": "4",
        "ParentRef": {
            "value": "2"
        }
    },
    {
        "DisplayName": "Sub SKU - Something Else Again",
        "Id": "5",
        "ParentRef": {
            "value": "2"
        }
    }
]
```

Example output:

```
data = {
    '2': [{
        'DisplayName': 'Sub SKU - Something Else',
        'ParentRef': {
            'value': '2'
        },
        'Id': '4'
    }, {
        'DisplayName': 'Sub SKU - Something Else Again',
        'ParentRef': {
            'value': '2'
        },
        'Id': '5'
    }],
    '1': [{
        'DisplayName': 'Sub SKU - Something',
        'ParentRef': {
            'value': '1'
        },
        'Id': '3'
    }]
}
```

Note: here I assumed the max depth of the tree is 2. If it can be deeper than that this solution will not work.

**Edit**: Thanks @alexis; input is built-in; use _input instead.

Comment: Small problem with this, which is why I was doing so many loops.  The API spits out the SKUs in a random sequence so I can't rely on the fact the ParentRef will already exist.  Sorry for the bad explanation.

Comment: Sure, then iterate twice. First create all the keys with the parent. And then reiterate. See the edited answer.

Comment: `input` is a python built-in, don't use it as a variable name. Ugly, confusing and agaist best practices.

Comment: Thanks Igor - massively appreciate it

Comment: @alexis Thanks. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the response is stored in a list of dict.

This works

```
res = [
{
    "DisplayName": "Main SKU 1",
    "Id": "1",
},
    {
    "DisplayName": "Main SKU 2",
    "Id": "2",
},
{
    "DisplayName": "Sub SKU - Something",
    "Id": "3",
    "ParentRef": {
    "value": "1"
    }
},
    {
    "DisplayName": "Sub SKU - Something Else",
    "Id": "4",
    "ParentRef": {
    "value": "2"
    }
},
    {
    "DisplayName": "Sub SKU - Something Else Again", 
    "Id": "5",
    "ParentRef": {
    "value": "2"
    }
}
]
count = 0
for item in res:
    parent_id = item.get('ParentRef',{}).get('value')
    if parent_id:
        for parent in res:
            if int(parent['Id']) == int(parent_id):
                count += 1
                parent_Name = parent["DisplayName"]
                print parent_Name
                print count, "Sub Product (s)"
                print item.get("DisplayName")
                print "Id", item.get("Id")
```

Output is

```
Main SKU 1
1 Sub Product (s)
Sub SKU - Something
Id 3
Main SKU 2
2 Sub Product (s)
Sub SKU - Something Else
Id 4
Main SKU 2
3 Sub Product (s)
Sub SKU - Something Else Again
Id 5
[Finished in 0.0s]
```